# Basic while loops in Python

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, while-loop

I have been trying to make a simple game in Python 3.3.4, at the beginning of the game I want the user to select a difficulty between 1 and 3 and if they put in another character other than 1, 2 or 3 they receive the message 'Invalid input'.

I have written the code below, however I cannot get it to function correctly in the even if the user does input 1, 2 or 3 it will come up with the error 'invalid input', I have tried messing around with it in various combinations with no avail. I understand that this is rather basic an probably something simple that I am overlooking as I am new to Python. Thanks in advance.

```
while True:
    while True:
        cmd = input('Please select a diffuculty from 1 to 3, with three being the hardest: ')
        if cmd in (1, 2, 3):
            break
        print ('Invalid input.')
    if cmd == 1:
        dopt = 3
        continue
    elif cmd == 2:
        dopt = 4
        continue
    elif cmd == 2:
        dopt = 5
        continue
```

Comment: In python 3 the input function returns strings, not integers.  `cmd in ('1', '2', '3')`?

Comment: Also, there is no way to leave your outer most `while`...

Comment: You can convert the string inputs to integers using `int(input("..."))`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: @AndyG Yes, but then his program blows up with a value error if someone inputs 'a'. I think he'd rather tell the user the input was bad.

Comment: @stewSquared Yes, of course. I was essentially pointing out what the issue is. It is much better to accept the string input, and then separately check whether it is an integer.

Comment: @AndyG Agreed. I didn't mean to insinuate that you overlooked this, but I suspect George would find the observation helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the doc:

`input([prompt])`

> Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).

`raw_input([prompt])`:

> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a **string** (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

I modified your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

while True:
    cmd = int(input('Please select a diffuculty from 1 to 3, with three being the hardest: '))
    print("cmd:{}, type:{}".format(cmd, type(cmd)))
    if cmd not in (1, 2, 3):
        print ('Invalid input.')
        continue
    if cmd == 1:
        dopt = 3
        break
    elif cmd == 2:
        dopt = 4
        break
    elif cmd == 3:
        dopt = 5
        break

print ("cmd:{}; dopt:{}".format(cmd, dopt))
```

You can use `type` to know what's the type of your input.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your types. `input` returns a string, so `cmd` is a string. You then ask if `cmd` is in `(1,2,3)`, a tuple of ints. Let me go through your options with you.

You can change

```
cmd = input("...")
```

to

```
cmd = int(input("..."))
```

That way, cmd is an int, as expected later on. The problem with this is that is someone enters something that's not parsable as an int, say `"foo"`, you're program will immediately exit with a ValueError.

Try something like this instead:

```
...
while True:
    cmd = input('Please select a diffuculty from 1 to 3, with three being the hardest: ')
    if cmd in ('1', '2', '3'):
        break
    print ('Invalid input.')
cmd = int(cmd)
if cmd == 1:
    dopt = 3
    continue
...
```

Here, you've a tuple of strings instead of a tuple of ints in the cmd validation. After, cmd is parsed as an int, and your program continues as expected.

On another note, your if-else chain can be replaced with `dopt = cmd+2`

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is one problem with your code.

1. `input()` returns a **string**, not an integer.

Because your input is a **string**, checking if a **string** is in a tuple of integers, would not work:

```
>>> tup = (1, 2, 3)
>>> '1' in tup
False
>>> '3' in tup
False
```

Therefore, you can cast `int()` to your `input()`, so that it takes integers and **only integers** as input:

```
>>> x = int(input())
4
>>> type(x)
<class 'int'>
>>> x = int(input())
'hello'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "'hello'"
>>>
```

Because of that, you can then check if the input is in your tuple:

```
>>> tup = (1, 2, 3)
>>> x = int(input())
2
>>> x in tup
True
>>> x = int(input())
7
>>> x in tup
False
>>>
```

Here is your edited code:

```
while True:
    while True:
        cmd = int(input('Please select a diffuculty from 1 to 3, with three being the hardest: '))
        if cmd in (1, 2, 3):
            break
        print ('Invalid input.')
    if cmd == 1:
        dopt = 3
        continue
    elif cmd == 2:
        dopt = 4
        continue
    elif cmd == 2:
        dopt = 5
        continue
```

Comment: `input` CAN return an `int`, in fact, it can even return a `list`. input parses the string for you, in you want the raw input use... `raw()`

Comment: @CristianGarcia, `raw_input()` doesn't exist in [tag:python-3.x]

Comment: ohhhh... then ignore my comment ;)